# How to get hours and minutes in this code mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, time

```
sql_exec (($sql = "insert into posts (user_id, body, picture_url, stamp) values ($userid, '". sql_escape ($body). "','$picture_url', minute(), hour())"));
```

sql_exec function

```
function sql_exec ($sql)
{
    global $my_conn;

    $result = mysqli_query($my_conn, $sql);

    return $result;
}
```

My problem is with the minute() and hour() they are not working

Comment: What are you expecting? I don't think hour() is a native PHP function

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: What isn't working about it? What value are you getting in those fields? What is the type of those fields?

Comment: ok sorry for bad question this is my first time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting a column count error? You appear to be trying to insert 5 values in to 4 columns.

If you are looking to store a timestamp against each post you might find it easier, and a lot more practical for querying, to define the `stamp` column as

```
`stamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

This will get you both date and time which will allow you sort the posts properly and the column default will mean you don't even have to supply a value for it, mysql will do it for you.

Comment: worked thank you so much and also everybody else who tryed problem was mine!

Comment: @cenka You are welcome, but you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't show up as 'unanswered'.

Comment: XD after year its now done im professional fullstack developer now!

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, PHP doesn't have any **minute()** nor **hour()** functions. What I do know, however, is that you can get both of them using PHP's **date()** function.

To get the current hour and minutes, you can use:

```
$hour = date('H');
$minute = date('i');
```

Please let me know if this helped you :)

Comment: The minute/hour functions are in the SQL query, so it's not trying to call a PHP function there.

Comment: In that case, according to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) you need to specify what it is you want to take the minute of. So in a way I think you do need to use it.

Comment: The MySQL native way to do it would be `HOUR(NOW()), MINUTE(NOW())`